# Close and Reopen Java Window Every Minute

Tags: java, awt, jfreechart

I'm working on an app that uses Java and JFreeChart. In my main I want to use a timer to close a window/object of the class and create a new object and window of the class. JFreeChart's dynamic capabilities don't seem to work with the APIs that I'm using and this is about the only way I can give the graph a dynamic feel.

The below code is what I currently have for the main, but all that it does is open one window and then close it and open a new one a minute later. Obviously, it's pretty clear why that's all that happens, but I can't seem to think of a good way to make it so that it creates and deletes the objects all within the timer.

```
  public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    final String host = "";
    final String username = "";
    final String password = "";
    final String id = "testStream"; 

    final GraphStream demo = new GraphStream("Dia Example graph", host, username, password, id);
    demo.pack();
    RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen(demo);
    demo.setVisible(true);
    new java.util.Timer().schedule( 
            new java.util.TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    demo.setVisible(false);
                    demo.dispose();
                    try {
                        final GraphStream demo2 =new GraphStream("Dia Example graph", host, username, password, id);
                        demo2.pack();
                        RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen(demo2);
                        demo2.setVisible(true);
                    } catch (DataServiceException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, 
            60000); 
}

}
```

Comment: Regularly recreating the window seems like a bad idea. Recreating the panel with-in the window would be a much more usable solution. Also, have you asked a question about the JFreeChart api? It seems like you decided on a work around that gives you another problem, instead of solving the core issue.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to split the constructor into a minimalist constructor and a refresh method:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
   final String host = "";
   final String username = "";
   final String password = "";
   final String id = "testStream"; 
   final GraphStream demo = new GraphStream( "Dia Example graph" );
   new java.util.Timer().schedule( 
      new java.util.TimerTask() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
            demo.refresh( host, username, password, id );
            demo.pack();
            RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen(demo);
            demo.setVisible( true );
         }
      }, 
      0, 60000); 
}
```

[As you can see timer.schedule()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long%29) may has 3 parameters to start immediately.